# I want to us a value from the URL as the condition of my sql data source sql Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code, but when I run it, I get no results:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            BindDataList();
            DataSet ds = GetData();
            r1.DataSource = ds;
            r1.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Code to populate the repeater starts here:HERE

```
    private DataSet GetData()
    {  
        //GET VALUE FROM URL
        this.Target = Request.QueryString["Loctn"];
        Citytxt.Text = Target;
        String cs = "Data Source=KISAKA;Initial Catalog=ACCOMMODATION;Integrated Security=True;";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ACC_Facility where Location_City = '"+ Target +"'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
}
```

Comment: Any assistance  would be much help as i  am green in coding

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: 1. check if your query returns rows. 2. Your sql query invites **SQL Injection Attack**. NEVER concatenate user input in sql query. the page url may look like this `page.aspx?loctn=';drop+table+acc_facility--`

Comment: A Data Source for SQL Client should have both a Sever Name and Instance of the database.  A backslash should separate the name and instance.  It looks like you are missing the instance.  To get instance open SQL Sever Management Studio.  The instance will be in the login window.

Comment: The Code runs and the returns rows if the SqlAdaptet is ("Select * from ACC_Facility") or ("Select * from ACC_Facility where Location_City = "Cape Town"") but when i add (where Location_City = '"+ Target +"'") i get zero results